# Ocultar el texto de los elementos a cuando este en vista mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

me encuentro con un problema peculiar,

Me gustaría ocultar con display block el texto de las etiquetas a cuando la pantalla este en modo mobile.

Solamente deseo ocultar el texto de todos los elementos para que cuando este en mobile se vean solo los iconos de fontawesome.

#### Este es mi código:

```
<div class="navegacion">
          <a href="#"><i class="fad fa-code link"></i> elemento 1</a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fad fa-laptop-code link"></i> elemento 2</a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fad fa-brackets-curly link"></i> elemento 3</a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fad fa-books link"></i> elemento 4</a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fad fa-video link"></i> elemento 5</a>
        </div>
```

```
.navegacion{
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```
var aLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navegacion a");aLinks[0];

function miFuncion(x) {
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
        
    } 
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)")
miFuncion(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(miFuncion) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Gracias por tu ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas javascript para esto, lo puedes hacer con css y media querys. Simplemente añade un span que contenga el texto a mostrar/ocultar. Luego estableces el tamaño máximo de pantalla hasta el que no se mostrará el texto y listo...

```css
.navegacion {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navegacion a span {
  display: inline;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .navegacion a span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navegacion">
  <a href="#"><i class="fad fa-code link"></i> <span>elemento 1</span></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fad fa-laptop-code link"></i> <span>elemento 2</span></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fad fa-brackets-curly link"></i> <span>elemento 3</span></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fad fa-books link"></i> <span>elemento 4</span></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fad fa-video link"></i> <span>elemento 5</span></a>
</div>
```